# Is there a macro to toggle to a specific folder in Outlook?

Tags: outlook-2007

I often (using the mouse) switch between 1 of 3 favorite folders under my inbox.  I am looking to write a macro to switch between these folders.  I see lots of emails on code to move specific emails to folders but is there a way to move focus on a specific folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, you could just change the `CurrentFolder` value to one of your Inbox folders. Here's an example of changing views from wherever I am to a folder named "T1" which is under the Inbox.

```
Sub ChangeViewtoFolderT1()

    Dim ns As Outlook.NameSpace
    Set ns = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    Dim Exp As Outlook.Explorer
    Set Exp = Application.ActiveExplorer

    Dim myInbox As Folder
    Set myInbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

    Dim folder1 As Folder
    Set folder1 = myInbox.Folders.Item("T1")

    Set Exp.CurrentFolder = folder1

End Sub
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb220039.aspx for more details.